# jqGrid insert @ between date and time

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, special-characters

I'm somewhat new to jqGrid and wondering about how to insert an @ symbol between the date and time when it's output.  I'm posting here because I have to send this to engineers who deploy it on the server and I'd like to get an opinion on this before I send it.  Unfortunately right now I don't have a way to test this on the fly.

What I have now is:

```
formatoptions: {srcformat:'Y-m-d H:i:s',newformat:'m/d/Y H:i:s'}
```

And that works just fine to read the input and display the date and time accurately.  My question is, I'd like to achieve something like 05/10/2012 @ 02:11:53 in the date/time column.  Would something like this be appropriate?

```
formatoptions: {srcformat:'Y-m-d H:i:s',newformat:'m/d/Y' + '@' + 'H:i:s'}
```

Thanks for any responses. :-)

Edit: to be more clear about why I can't test this, it's because they have a server environment set up to read json data into the jqgrid table.  i can test jquery on my local environment for most things, but I don't have the ability to read in the same json data they're using...

Comment: Did you try `newformat:'m/d/Y @ H:i:s'`?

Comment: I did not, but that makes sense.  Sorry for the newbie question, I know people are supposed to deploy and test before posting here, but I don't have the capability right now.  I have to send it to engineering and "hope it works" when it's something I'm not sure about.

Thank you for your reply Joy :-)

Comment: I just heard back, the first thing I posted totally worked -> `formatoptions: {srcformat:'Y-m-d H:i:s',newformat:'m/d/Y' + '@' + 'H:i:s'}`

Comment: Actually `newformat:'m/d/Y @ H:i:s'` and `newformat:'m/d/Y' + '@' + 'H:i:s'}` are equivalent and and both should work fine.

Comment: no they are not :) (hint: spaces)